# Parse Or Regex Query Gives Geoquery Error

Tags: regex, parse-platform

I am using a Parse OR query to find user matches based on regex and emails within an array. The regex can be quite long as I am generating it from names in the user's address book. My code is below:

```
    PFQuery *emailQuery = [WPUser query];
    [emailQuery whereKey:@"email" containedIn:emails];

    PFQuery *nameQuery = [WPUser query];
    [nameQuery whereKey:@"name" matchesRegex:regex modifiers:@"i"];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[emailQuery, nameQuery]];
    [query whereKey:@"objectId" notEqualTo:[WPUser currentUser].objectId];
    [query whereKeyExists:@"signedUp"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        self.registeredContacts = objects;
        BLOCK_ON_MAINTHREAD()
    }];
```

The regex format is `(^First.*Last$)|(^First.*Last$)` etc. for each name in the address book. I use the `i` modifier to make it case insensitive.

However, I get a weird error with this query and it seems to have only begun recently: `[Error]: geo query within or is not supported (Code: 102, Version: 1.14.2)`. I am not adding any geo constraints to this query as you can see. If my regex somehow causing Parse to add a geoquery? If I comment out the line of `matchesRegex:modifiers:` then the query returns as normal...however I am obviously losing the functionality I need.

I do not have symbols or anything as I am also validating names with an `NSCharacterSet`.

```
NSMutableCharacterSet *validCharacters = [NSMutableCharacterSet letterCharacterSet];
[validCharacters formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

Why is Parse giving me an error that has no relation to my actual query? If it is related to my regex, any ideas on avoiding it?

Answer (score 0):

I have some Chinese names in my address book and for some reason these names were causing the error I added a line in checking my regex to skip these names and the error is gone.

For reference I added a `BOOL` check:

```
BOOL isLatin = [regexName canBeConvertedToEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
```